# Intellij -Error running "python_script.py" : com/intellij/docker/remove/DockerCredentialsType

Tags: intellij-idea

While attempting to *debug* a very simple python script inside `Intellij` the following error is intermittently occurring:

[image]

I have recently installed `Intellij 2018.3` and did not even select Docker support.  The program does not do *any* networking related activity.

Any thoughts on where this error is coming from?

Comment: Report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the logs attached.

Comment: @CrazyCoder just did that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `Docker` integration is enabled *by default*.   I have disabled that plugin: let's see if the error above no longer appears.

[image]

**Update**  disabling the plugin did not have an effect.  Issue has been reported at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206002

> [image]